# SharePoint Column Value Trigger Condition - Are Both BingAI and ChatGPT Wrong?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

If you ask BingAI the following: "I want to trigger a flow when a choice column in a sharepoint list changes from value x to value y. Provide an example trigger condition." then it will happily provide the following:

```
@and(
    @equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Status/Value'], 'Completed'),
    @not(equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Status/Value'], triggerOutputs()?['oldValues/Status/Value'])))
```

Which boils down to **exactly** what I want, thus:

> Check that the current value of field **Status** is 'Completed', then
> check that this is different to its old value and, if so, run the
> flow.

I cross-checked this with ChatGPT v3.5 using prompt: "Is the following Trigger Condition valid? ....." and it confidently responded 'Yes', then went on to correctly explain its function.

But when I put this Trigger Condition into my flow, I receive the error, "*The input parameter(s) of operation 'When_an_item_or_a_file_is_modified' contains invalid expression(s).*"

I can only assume that this was maybe once-upon-a-time a valid expression, and that's what both BingAI and ChatGPT were trained on?

1. Has anybody successfully used this **"oldValues"** function before? Does it still exist? Did it once exist?
2. Has anybody found a **Trigger Condition** that can check a current field value against its previous value?
3. Is the only solution here to actually run the flow on **all** list item changes, then use an action to conditionally stop it e.g. 'Get changes for an item or a file' or manually checking against a 'copy-of' column?

Comment: All the trigger does is act on the data it’s given. There’s no oldValues function, it would need to be in the data set. Paste an example trigger body into your question and I’ll tell you if it’s possible.

Comment: The trigger condition was provided at the top, but I don't think the 'oldValues' part exists now, or maybe ever existed!

Comment: I don't want the trigger condition, I want the body of a trigger itself.  If you can paste it in, it will answer the question.

Comment: The solutions I've seen for using a specific field for 'SharePoint item or file modified' trigger, use a helper field (e.g. Status_Trigger) which you set equal to your desired field (e.g. Status) when item is created. In the flow where you're checking if item is modified, you would check for condition if 'Status equals Status_Trigger'. After completing actions you would again set that field (Status_Trigger) equal to desired field (Status) to avoid infinite loop. Since no one mentioned oldValues function, I'm guessing it's not used (anymore). I'm also stuck on invalid expression/s error though.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently still a lot of hallucination going on in Power Automate Copilot.

What you want to achieve can be done with a different action. Let the workflow trigger when the item has changed. Following that, you can use the action "Get changes for an item or file (Properties only)". Now you can check if the most recent change was for the "Status" field and if the Status is now "completed".

If not, just terminate the workflow.

With this approach, the workflow will trigger on any change, but you only let it run to the end if the desired field has the desired value.

Comment: That solution was described in bullet 3, not ideal but maybe my only option. I'm just not keen on running 'when an item is modified' flows when the only time I actually want to run the flow is when 'a very specific thing' is modified, and that's what Trigger Conditions are for.

I might just have to 'limit' the triggering to when a column = something (e.g. 'Status = 'Completed'), that's straightforward enough, then use the 'Get changes for an item or file (Properties only)' to check for the change from X to Y. At least then it will only be triggering when the column is a specific value.